# Gallery keep stopping error, after including Fileprovider for API 24 and above

Tags: android

After i updated the code to include Fileprovider for API 24 and above, i am getting the error "Gallery keeps stopping".

Below is the code segment for capturing image from camera and performing crop and saving it.

When i traced the code, it execute till startActivityForResult(cropIntent,3) in performcrop() then gives the above error. (Note: there is not much info in error dump, Tested on Nexus 7.0).

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {




        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == 2)
        {


            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            Bitmap var_Bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            var_Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

            try {

                OutputStream out;
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
                File createDir = new File(root+"master"+File.separator);
                createDir.mkdir();


                File file = new File(root + "master" + File.separator +"master.jpg");

                file.createNewFile();
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                out.write(bytes);
                out.close();
                path1=root + "master" + File.separator +"master.jpg";
                //imageUri= Uri.fromFile(file);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
                imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(RecognizeActivity.this,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                        file);
                else
                    imageUri= Uri.fromFile(file);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }

            performCrop();


        } else if (requestCode==3)
        {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            Bitmap var_Bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ui_imageView_browse);
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(var_Bitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            var_Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

            try {

                OutputStream out;
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
                File createDir = new File(root+"master"+File.separator);
                createDir.mkdir();


                File file = new File(root + "master" + File.separator +"master.jpg");

                file.createNewFile();
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                out.write(bytes);
                out.close();
                path1=root + "master" + File.separator +"master.jpg";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }


            ImageView imageView_error = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ui_imageView_error);

            imageView_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView_error.setImageResource(R.drawable.process);

            userupdate();
            if(netcheck==0)
            {
                FeedTask ft = new FeedTask();
                ft.execute(path1);
            }







        }


    }


    public void performCrop() {
        // take care of exceptions
        try {
            // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
            // support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "false");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent,3);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: use `data.getUri()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around , targetSdkVersion is set to 23 in manifest file and removed the Fileprovider path code segment and it is working fine.